# When to use [printer] vs [printing]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just came across [printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer) and [printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printing).

Is it useful to keep both? When to use which one?

Answer (score 8):

After glancing over questions tagged with both, it seems to me that:

- [printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer) relates to a printer, e.g. physical hardware device that creates images on paper, questions related to printer drivers, printer maintenance, printer consumables, etc. Usually such questions mention a specific printer.
- [printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printing) relates to a *process* of creating such hardcopy images on paper, e.g. printer spoolers/queues (CUPS, Windows spooler, etc.), support of printing in different OSes/applications, and these questions usually do not mention a specific printer model, as they are more generic.

I think it is useful to have both tags.

Comment: Either could refer to virtual printers too (e.g. PDF printers), but I think you are correct in the distinction that [tag:printing] refers to the process (e.g. printing *from* a program, or otherwise printer-agnostic) whereas [tag:printer] refers to the device (virtual or physical) to be printed to.